# in the (time) vs in (time)

Tags: phrase-usage, articles, time

I know "in the morning" is correct and "in morning" is not. 
But why are **"in the summer" and "in summer" both correct**? How do you know when to use an article or not?

Can someone explain this?

Comment: Interesting question. I suppose _in summer_ refers to the summer season in general ("It's pleasant to walk in the fields in summer".) and _in the summer_ to the summer of a particular year.